# How do I decide the percentage of image similarity in openCV

Tags: c#, python, c++, opencv, computer-vision

I'm working on a project that is related to duplicate document detection. I've have spent hours and hours googling and learning a lot about OpenCV (it's been a really tough, but an interesting experience altogether, I'm definitely going to start a blog this after everything!). I plan on using BRISK\AKAZE detectors together with FREAK descriptors and LSH matching to compare each document (because the documents are mainly black and white), but I need to calculate exactly how similar the two images are based on percentage, to enable my software make simple decisions afterwards.

I'm open to any ideas or suggestions on my project, and I would love if anyone would be so nice to share some code together with their answers to save me the time of googling my way there :-). Thanks.

**EDIT:**
Here are samples to explain my problem.

[image: This is an original document.]

[image: Here is document one, but re-scanned, and slightly rotated]

[image: Here is a similar image.]

Image 1 is the document I need to get the match for. It is very similar to the all the other documents, but it is different from Image 3, after matching it should have similarity percentage of maybe 90% to Image 3. Image 2 is a duplicate of Image 1, it has been re-scanned and was slightly rotated in the process, it can have a 95% - 98% similarity since it's features are very similar to image 1. Thanks Everyone :).

Comment: "I'm open to any ideas or suggestions on my project" Here's one: Pick a language.

Comment: @DimChtz OpenCV can be implemented in any of those languages, I can easily port them over to C#, if they work. I found very few OpenCV solutions on the internet that were in C#.

Comment: @DimChtz Will you upvote my question back if I pick one? :-) I'm working within a deadline here...

Comment: I didn't downvote you :)

Comment: First define _similarity_, then we can talk about it... the max similarity is if the two docs have: same words? Same # of colums? Same % black pixels? Same topic? Same what?

Comment: @Miki Correct me if I'm wrong :), but similarity should be based on the good matches after the LSH match. The more the features (in this case words\letters) are alike, the more similar the two documents are.

Comment: The more patches 32x32 (or whatever the freak neighbourhood is) are similar, the more two docs are similar. Ok. But you can have similar patches in random positions and still have the same # of matches

Comment: @Miki Thanks a lot for the analysis, I can't be grateful enough :). You do have a point, mistakes can be made using that method but it seems to be the best I could figure out when dealing with documents that can loose quality, or be slightly rotated after they have been scanned. If you have any better ideas, please share :). Cheers.

Comment: You can show a few of your images to get a better understanding of the problem

Comment: @Miki I have applied an edit with a few documents. I hope my approach is okay :).

Comment: Uh, you're looking for very small differences in the content, while the images may vary a lot. I guess my first approach would be 1) align/register the images, 2) subtract the aligned images 3) remove small differences (noise). Ideally you end up with a mask with only the real differences.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158185/discussion-between-prince-owen-and-miki).

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [SSIM](http://www.cns.nyu.edu/~lcv/ssim/). (Structural Similarity Index). It returns a 0-1 score based on similarities in image structure and pixel values. I don't believe that OpenCV has a pre-made solution for it but there are loads of tutorials for writing your own in OpenCV.

Comment: This is an index for image quality... that's another story...

Comment: No. It is an index that determines whether pixel neighborhoods are dissimilar. It has applications in determining the quality of certain image processing algorithms (like compression) but that is not it's only use.

Comment: But you need to align them first, am I right?

Comment: Correct. It performs a pixel-wise kernel based comparison, so the images would need to be registered first.

Comment: That's good info to add to your answer ;)